# QtOpenGL and MacOS X -- Software rendering?

Tags: macos, opengl, qt4, qglwidget

I'm developing a cross-platform application and am not very familiar with the Mac platform. I use Qt for the GUI. I use a QGLWidget to make sure the drawing (with QPainter) is done in OpenGL.

My project built fine in XCode and runs. However, drawing is slow as hell, in situations where on Windows and Linux machines speed is not an issue. The Macbook has an Nvidia GPU, whereas the Windows machine has only onboard intel graphics.

When I look at the binary, it seems that while linking to QtOpenGL lib, it does not explicitely link to the GL lib itself.

- How can I test if hardware acceleration is working or software fallback rendering is doing the job?
- Shouldn't my binary link to the GL lib, or is this hidden as being a recursive dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see what OpenGL implementation is using is to print the value of glGetString(GL_VENDOR) and glGetString(GL_RENDERER), this should help pinpoint the problem.